# Undocumented windows built-in PDF renderer capabilities?

Tags: c#, pdf, windows-10, uwp, microsoft-edge

Using the `Windows.Data.Pdf` namespace, i am able to render pdf (as an image) without using any third party library.

**If im not mistaken**, Microsoft's Edge browser uses the same library to render pdfs (Windows.Data.Pdf.dll). By looking at the official `Windows.Data.Pdf` documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.data.pdf) i can see it's only about

> *converting a page in a Portable Document Format (PDF) document to an **image** file.*

but, Edge browser has "search text" capability when rendering a pdf, which i cannot find anywhere in the `Windows.Data.Pdf` library.

My question is, is there any undocumented (hence unofficial) capabilities available to use in the `Windows.Data.Pdf` namespace (or somewhere else built-in in windows)? (Specifically, the search text function, which i assume i must be able to a) extract the text of pdf so i can search on it, and b) get the XY of the string occurence on the rendered page so i can highlight it somehow)

Comment: I can't find anything showing that Edge is using the .Net Framework. So i think Edge uses a custom non-public PDF-Library.

Comment: @AlexH i know, it [smells like adobe](http://www.windowscentral.com/microsoft-confirms-its-new-edge-browser-wont-support-its-silverlight-player#comment-1885465) under the hood. of course that's just speculation, i hope someone can provide a decent answer :/

Comment: @AlexH also [here](http://blog.trendmicro.com/trendlabs-security-intelligence/windows-10s-new-browser-microsoft-edge-improved-but-also-new-risks/) trend labs says Edge **is** using the module `windows.data.pdf.dll`

Comment: Thank you. That's an very interesting article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The library used by general Windows 10 apps is not the same as `windows.data.pdf.dll`, it's simply a namespace defined in `Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract`

[image]

On the other hand, `Windows.Data.Pdf.dll` is a native function library, so you need to see if you can get `DllImport` to work with it.

EDIT: Here is the output of DependencyWalker of `Windows.Data.Pdf.dll` The function that interests you is probably [PdfCreateRenderer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn302145(v=vs.85).aspx)

[image]

Comment: For anyone reaching here. DependencyWalker does not work on Windows 10.
Use Dependencies, as per this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40549702/dependency-walker-hangs

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late response but i guess it's never too late.
Windows.Data.Pdf only supports rendering operations. Format specific operations like Search, Annotation enumeration etc are not exposed in the Windows.Data.Pdf library.
Also Windows components do not rely on Windows.Data.Pdf

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, is there any undocumented (hence unofficial) capabilities available to use in the Windows.Data.Pdf namespace (or somewhere else built-in in windows)? (Specifically, the search text function, which i assume i must be able to a) extract the text of pdf so i can search on it, and b) get the XY of the string occurence on the rendered page so i can highlight it somehow)

The C:\Windows\system32\Windows.Data.Pdf.dll file (which is something different than the `Windows.Data.Pdf`  namespace, as pointed out by Kanadaj) does indeed provide text extraction capabilities. However, this feature is not provided as a .NET library but rather via the **IFilter** interface used by Windows Search.

Here's a screenshot using nirsoft's SearchFilterView tool:

[image: screenshot]

**IFilter** is a COM interface, not a .NET interface. It *can* be used from .NET code, although a bit of translation boilerplate is required. This related question contains all the details and a code example:

- [Using IFilter in C# and retrieving file from database rather than file system](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7313828/87698)

Answer (score 1):

`Windows.Data.Pdf` has indeed a text extraction feature (beyond its rendering feature). It's not totally undocumented, as it's based on Windows Search's [IFilter interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/filter/nn-filter-ifilter) as others saids.

Here is some self-sufficient code that allows you to extract all texts but also custom properties (such as author, title, dates, etc.) of any .PDF file. It uses a stream as inpout so you can search files but also in-memory PDFs, etc.

Example usage:

```
static void Main()
{
    foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"D:\allmybooks", "*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(file);
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(file))
        {
            foreach (var obj in PdfExtractor.ExtractObjects(stream))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(obj.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Extractor utility:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
using System.Text;

namespace PdfUtilities
{
    public static class PdfExtractor
    {
        private static Guid _windowsDataPdfFilterClsid = new Guid("6c337b26-3e38-4f98-813b-fba18bab64f5");

        // this wraps pure text and custom values (author, title, etc.)
        public sealed class PdfObject
        {
            public object Value { get; internal set; } // is string if IsText or can be anything otherwise (datetime, etc.)
            public bool IsText { get; internal set; } // this is pure text
            public string PropertyName { get; internal set; } // System.Author, System.Title, etc.

            public override string ToString()
            {
                if (IsText)
                    return Value?.ToString();

                return PropertyName + ": " + Value;
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<PdfObject> ExtractObjects(Stream stream, bool throwOnError = false)
        {
            if (stream == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(stream));

            var type = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(_windowsDataPdfFilterClsid);
            var filter = (IFilter)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            var init = (IInitializeWithStream)filter;
            var chunkText = new StringBuilder(80000); // under LOH
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            var mis = new ManagedIStream(stream);
            var hr = init.Initialize(mis, 0);
            if (hr < 0)
            {
                if (!throwOnError)
                    yield break;

                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
            }

            hr = filter.Init(0, 0, null, out _);
            if (hr < 0)
            {
                if (!throwOnError)
                    yield break;

                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
            }

            do
            {
                hr = filter.GetChunk(out var chunk);
                if (hr < 0)
                    break;

                if (chunk.flags.HasFlag(CHUNKSTATE.CHUNK_TEXT))
                {
                    do
                    {
                        var size = chunkText.Capacity;
                        hr = filter.GetText(ref size, chunkText);
                        if (hr < 0)
                            break;

                        sb.Append(chunkText);

                        const int FILTER_S_LAST_TEXT = 0x41709;
                        if (hr == FILTER_S_LAST_TEXT)
                            break;
                    }
                    while (true);
                    yield return new PdfObject { Value = sb.ToString(), IsText = true };
                }

                if (chunk.flags.HasFlag(CHUNKSTATE.CHUNK_VALUE))
                {
                    string name;
                    if (chunk.attribute.psProperty.ulKind == PRSPEC.PRSPEC_PROPID)
                    {
                        var pk = new PROPERTYKEY { fmtid = chunk.attribute.guidPropSet, propid = chunk.attribute.psProperty.propid.ToInt32() };
                        if (PSGetNameFromPropertyKey(ref pk, out name) < 0)
                        {
                            name = chunk.attribute.guidPropSet.ToString("B") + " " + chunk.attribute.psProperty.propid;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (chunk.attribute.psProperty.ulKind == PRSPEC.PRSPEC_LPWSTR && chunk.attribute.psProperty.propid != IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        name = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(chunk.attribute.psProperty.propid);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        name = "???";
                    }

                    if (filter.GetValue(out var pv) >= 0)
                    {
                        if (PropVariantToVariant(pv, out var value) >= 0)
                        {
                            yield return new PdfObject { Value = value, PropertyName = name };
                        }
                        PropVariantClear(pv);
                    }
                }
            }
            while (true);
        }

        [DllImport("propsys")] // .NET knows how to handle VARIANT, not PROPVARIANT
        private static extern int PropVariantToVariant(IntPtr pPropVar, out object pVar);

        [DllImport("propsys")]
        private static extern int PSGetNameFromPropertyKey(ref PROPERTYKEY propkey, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] out string ppszCanonicalName);

        [DllImport("ole32")]
        private static extern int PropVariantClear(IntPtr pvar);

        [ComImport, Guid("89BCB740-6119-101A-BCB7-00DD010655AF"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
        private interface IFilter
        {
            [PreserveSig]
            int Init(IFILTER_INIT grfFlags, int cAttributes, FULLPROPSPEC[] aAttributes, out IFILTER_FLAGS pFlags);

            [PreserveSig]
            int GetChunk(out STAT_CHUNK pStat);

            [PreserveSig]
            int GetText(ref int pcwcBuffer, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder awcBuffer);

            [PreserveSig]
            int GetValue(out IntPtr ppPropValue);

            [PreserveSig]
            int BindRegion(FILTERREGION origPos, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid riid, IntPtr ppunk);
        }

        [ComImport, Guid("b824b49d-22ac-4161-ac8a-9916e8fa3f7f"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
        private interface IInitializeWithStream
        {
            [PreserveSig]
            int Initialize(IStream grfFlags, int mode);
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct FULLPROPSPEC
        {
            public Guid guidPropSet;
            public PROPSPEC psProperty;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct PROPSPEC
        {
            public PRSPEC ulKind;
            public IntPtr propid;// or lpwstr;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct PROPERTYKEY
        {
            public Guid fmtid;
            public int propid;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct STAT_CHUNK
        {
            public int idChunk;
            public CHUNK_BREAKTYPE breakType;
            public CHUNKSTATE flags;
            public int locale;
            public FULLPROPSPEC attribute;
            public int idChunkSource;
            public int cwcStartSource;
            public int cwcLenSource;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct FILTERREGION
        {
            public int idChunk;
            public int cwcStart;
            public int cwcExtent;
        }

        private enum CHUNK_BREAKTYPE
        {
            CHUNK_NO_BREAK = 0,
            CHUNK_EOW = 1,
            CHUNK_EOS = 2,
            CHUNK_EOP = 3,
            CHUNK_EOC = 4
        }

        [Flags]
        private enum CHUNKSTATE
        {
            CHUNK_TEXT = 0x1,
            CHUNK_VALUE = 0x2,
            CHUNK_FILTER_OWNED_VALUE = 0x4
        }

        [Flags]
        private enum IFILTER_INIT
        {
            IFILTER_INIT_CANON_PARAGRAPHS = 0x0001,
            IFILTER_INIT_HARD_LINE_BREAKS = 0x0002,
            IFILTER_INIT_CANON_HYPHENS = 0x0004,
            IFILTER_INIT_CANON_SPACES = 0x0008,
            IFILTER_INIT_APPLY_INDEX_ATTRIBUTES = 0x0010,
            IFILTER_INIT_APPLY_OTHER_ATTRIBUTES = 0x0020,
            IFILTER_INIT_APPLY_CRAWL_ATTRIBUTES = 0x0100,
            IFILTER_INIT_INDEXING_ONLY = 0x0040,
            IFILTER_INIT_SEARCH_LINKS = 0x0080,
            IFILTER_INIT_FILTER_OWNED_VALUE_OK = 0x0200,
            IFILTER_INIT_FILTER_AGGRESSIVE_BREAK = 0x0400,
            IFILTER_INIT_DISABLE_EMBEDDED = 0x0800,
            IFILTER_INIT_EMIT_FORMATTING = 0x1000,
        }

        private enum IFILTER_FLAGS
        {
            IFILTER_FLAGS_OLE_PROPERTIES = 1,
        }

        private enum PRSPEC
        {
            PRSPEC_LPWSTR = 0,
            PRSPEC_PROPID = 1,
        }

        [ComVisible(true)]
        private sealed class ManagedIStream : IStream
        {
            private readonly Stream _stream;
            public ManagedIStream(Stream stream) => _stream = stream;

            public void Read(byte[] pv, int cb, IntPtr pcbRead)
            {
                var read = _stream.Read(pv, 0, cb);
                if (pcbRead != IntPtr.Zero) { Marshal.WriteInt32(pcbRead, read); }
            }

            public void Seek(long dlibMove, int dwOrigin, IntPtr plibNewPosition)
            {
                var newPos = _stream.Seek(dlibMove, (SeekOrigin)dwOrigin);
                if (plibNewPosition != IntPtr.Zero) { Marshal.WriteInt64(plibNewPosition, newPos); }
            }

            public void Stat(out System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.STATSTG pstatstg, int grfStatFlag)
            {
                var stream = _stream;
                pstatstg = new System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.STATSTG
                {
                    cbSize = stream.Length,
                    type = 2, // STGTY_STREAM
                    grfMode = 0, // STGM_READ,
                };
            }

            public void Write(byte[] pv, int cb, IntPtr pcbWritten) => throw new NotSupportedException();
            public void CopyTo(IStream pstm, long cb, IntPtr pcbRead, IntPtr pcbWritten) => throw new NotSupportedException();
            public void SetSize(long libNewSize) => throw new NotSupportedException();
            public void Commit(int grfCommitFlags) => throw new NotSupportedException();
            public void Revert() => throw new NotSupportedException();
            public void LockRegion(long libOffset, long cb, int dwLockType) => throw new NotSupportedException();
            public void UnlockRegion(long libOffset, long cb, int dwLockType) => throw new NotSupportedException();
            public void Clone(out IStream ppstm) => throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```