# Initiliaze IFilter from IStream

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, com, ifilter

I'm using IFilter to index some MS Office docs. 
Loading from file is ok, all works great, like in all manuals and samples:

`HRESULT hr_f = LoadIFilter(filename, 0, (void **)&pFilter);`

However, using [BindIFilterFromStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690827%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API failed, and i cant figure out how to use it properly.

`HRESULT hr_ss = BindIFilterFromStream(spStream/*my IStream* impl*/, 0, (void **)&pFilter);`

I implemented the `IStream` interface, only the method (except `IUnknown`'s) invoked during initialization is:

```
HRESULT StreamFilter::Stat(STATSTG * pstatstg, DWORD grfStatFlag)
{
   //Microsoft Office Ifilter from Windows Registry
   const IID CLSID_IFilter = {
       0xf07f3920,
       0x7b8c,
       0x11cf,
       { 0x9b, 0xe8, 0x00, 0xaa, 0x00, 0x4b, 0x99, 0x86 }

       //{f07f3920-7b8c-11cf-9be8-00aa004b9986}
   };
   LARGE_INTEGER pSize;
   int fl = GetFileSizeEx(_hFile, &pSize);
   memset(pstatstg, 0, sizeof(STATSTG));
   pstatstg->clsid = CLSID_IFilter;
   pstatstg->type = STGTY_STREAM;
   pstatstg->cbSize.QuadPart = pSize.QuadPart;

   return S_OK;
}
```

After that `hr_ss` is `E_FAIL` and `IFilter` is `NULL`.

There are case [Using IFilter in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313828/using-ifilter-in-c-sharp-and-retrieving-file-from-database-rather-than-file-syst/19504946#19504946), and those method works great only for *.pdf in c++ too, but not for MSO docs...

Comment: From your link for BindIFilterFromStream: "Indexing Service is unsupported as of Windows XP" - what version of Windows are you trying this on?

Comment: hm, devmachine is windows 8.1, i've tested in win2k3 - same result that in my Win8 PC...  
seems i realized my mistake :( Is it means that in Windows, newer than WinXP i cant use this API? I'm sorry for my english...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to init `IFilter` properly, here is the code:

```
HRESULT hr = LoadIFilter(L".doc", 0, (void **)&pFilter);
IPersistStream *stream;
HRESULT hr_qi = pFilter->QueryInterface(&stream);

std::ifstream ifs(filename, ios::binary);
std::string content((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)),
    (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

IStream *comStream;
HGLOBAL hMem = ::GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, content.size());
LPVOID pDoc = ::GlobalLock(hMem);
memcpy(pDoc, content.c_str(), content.size());
::GlobalUnlock(hMem);
HRESULT hr_mem = ::CreateStreamOnHGlobal(hMem, true, &comStream);
HRESULT hr_stream_load = stream->Load(comStream);
```

And getting the text from your Document is like usual sample from MSDN

```
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
  DWORD flags = 0;
  HRESULT hr = pFilter->Init(IFILTER_INIT_INDEXING_ONLY |
                             IFILTER_INIT_APPLY_INDEX_ATTRIBUTES |
                             IFILTER_INIT_APPLY_CRAWL_ATTRIBUTES |
                             IFILTER_INIT_FILTER_OWNED_VALUE_OK |
                             IFILTER_INIT_APPLY_OTHER_ATTRIBUTES,
                             0, 0, &flags);
  if (FAILED(hr))
  {
     pFilter->Release();
     throw exception("IFilter::Init() failed");
  }

  Start();

  STAT_CHUNK stat;
  while (SUCCEEDED(hr = pFilter->GetChunk(&stat)))
  {
     if ((stat.flags & CHUNK_TEXT) != 0)
        ProcessTextChunk(pFilter, stat);

     if ((stat.flags & CHUNK_VALUE) != 0)
        ProcessValueChunk(pFilter, stat);
  }

  Finish();

  pFilter->Release();      
}
else
{
  throw exception("LoadIFilter() failed");
}
```

You do not need to implement your own IStream, just initiliaze it from your buffer...